# java.net.URISyntaxException in a library in Netbeans on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I am compiling a Java project on Mac OS X, and I have the following stackTrace when trying to build:

```
ant -f /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Created dir: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build
Updating property file: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build/built-   clean.properties
Deleting directory /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build
Updating property file: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build/classes
Created dir: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build/empty
Created dir: /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 4 source files to /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/build/classes
error: error reading /Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/framework/protoframework.jar; java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 76: file:/Users/hervegirod/Desktop/Java/VirtualCopilot/VirtualCopilot/framework/\
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

The exception is when the IDE tries to read a Java library I am using on my project. My project uses Java 11, and I am using a library which was built on Java 8 on Windows 10. I am using the last Netbeans version (12.6) to build my project. If I build the project on Windows and execute it on Mac OS X, I have no problem. The problem is only when I am trying to build it on Mac OS X with this library.

Also I have the same problem on Linux, or with another IDE (IntelliJ Idea). I initially suspected that my library files where not UTF8, but as far as I saw, they were (except if I did not look close enough). Note that I am able to investigate the library, because I am the one who develop it (on Windows).

Does somebody have a clue?

Comment: Look closely at the error message, at the very end of the file path. Note that it ends with /\. Isn't that backslash the _"Illegal character in path"_ on your MacOS build? And is it there because you initially created the project successfully on Windows, where back slashes in the file path are valid?

Comment: Is it possible that it is because of the Manifest? It is the only file where I use backslash characters, for the Class-Path property, for example: `Class-Path: lib/MDIUtilities-core-LGPL.jar \
            lib/MDIUtilities-ui-LGPL.jar`

Comment: [1] OK. A backslash in a URI is invalid. Can you just change that backslash to a forward slash? That might resolve your issue on macOS, but should still work fine on Windows, where forward slash will usually work just as well as backslash in a file path. [2] Can you run some utility on macOS to independently read the jar to see if the problem still occurs without building in NetBeans? But [don't use the **jar** utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) because _"All pathnames are displayed with forward slashes, regardless of the platform or operating system"_.

Comment: That said, I can't really explain why your Windows build works on macOS, yet your macOS build fails. Perhaps something in the build process on Windows is smart enough to translate the offending backslash to a forward slash, but the build process on macOS is not as smart? Also, make sure there are no spaces in any URI/file path.

Comment: Knowing te problem, i can't undertand why it is working on Mac OS, appart from the build. thanks, I will check this this evening (I don't have access to my Mac before this evening today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skopisa was right. The reason was this faulty manifest:

```
Main-Class: org.da.protoframework.model.core.Framework
Class-Path: lib/MDIUtilities-core-LGPL.jar \
            lib/MDIUtilities-ui-LGPL.jar \
            lib/scriptHelper.jar \
            lib/scriptHelperGroovy.jar \
            lib/scriptHelperSwing.jar \
            lib/groovy-3.0.7-indy.jar \
            lib/jna.jar \
            lib/jna-platform.jar \
            lib/json.jar \
            lib/jEditor.jar \
            lib/netty-all.jar
```

Strangely, it worked correctly on Linux or Mac OS X when using the library, but building was impossible because of the backslash character ("").

This version is correct and work correctly on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X, for both runtime and building a program using this library:

```
Main-Class: org.da.protoframework.model.core.Framework
Class-Path: lib/MDIUtilities-core-LGPL.jar
            lib/MDIUtilities-ui-LGPL.jar
            lib/scriptHelper.jar
            lib/scriptHelperGroovy.jar
            lib/scriptHelperSwing.jar
            lib/groovy-3.0.7-indy.jar
            lib/jna.jar
            lib/jna-platform.jar
            lib/json.jar
            lib/jEditor.jar
            lib/netty-all.jar
```